# Can you auto-generate code for assigning properties of an object in C#? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, autocomplete

Example:  I am working with an API that has definitions for various objects with many properties.

This object has about 40 properties, and I'd like to set them all.

Is there a way to auto-generate the following code from an object?

```
contact.AddressId = null;
contact.Anniversary = null;
contact.AssistantId = null;
contact.BirthDay = null;
contact.Children = null;
contact.CompanyAddressInfo = null;
contact.CompanyIdentifier = null;
contact.DisablePortalLogin = null;
contact.Email = null;
contact.Emails = null;
contact.ExtensionData = null;
contact.Fax = null;
contact.Faxes = null;
contact.FaxExt = null;
contact.FirstName = null;
contact.Gender = null;
contact.Id = null;
contact.Inactive = null;
contact.LastName = null;
contact.LastUpdated = null;
contact.ManagerId = null;
contact.Married = null;
contact.NickName = null;
contact.PersonalAddress = null;
contact.PersonalAddressFlag = null;
contact.Phone = null;
contact.PhoneExt = null;
contact.Phones = null;
contact.PortalPassword = null;
contact.PortalSecurityLevel = null;
contact.Relationship = null;
contact.School = null;
contact.SID = null;
contact.SignificantOther = null;
contact.SiteName = null;
contact.Title = null;
contact.Type = null;
contact.UnsubscribeFlag = null;
contact.UpdatedBy = null;
```

The purpose is for visualization and for me to see what I am and am not setting in my code.

Edited to be more specific.

Comment: Nothing in particular, even a placeholder comment would be fine.  I'm merely looking for a way to enumerate all of the properties into codes that I can work with.

Comment: Not built in, though I imagine you could probably accomplish this with a custom snippet.

Comment: If you do not have specific values, they will be set to default values like 0/null anyway.

Comment: Right, `null` would actually be great, it's really just a convenience thing that would lay it out for me so I can begin to assign variables as necessary.  Oh well.

Comment: If the properties are reference type, they all will be initialized to null automatically. You don't have to write any code.

Comment: See edit for clarity.  I understand that the values will default if I do not set them; I want to see what I am and am not setting as I go.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So using [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637265/4479934) I've created a method that accepts an object and a name, and spits out all properties with `null` as a placeholder, as shown in the question:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectGenerateNullValues(new Contact(), "contact");
    }

    private static void ObjectGenerateNullValues(object objectType, string objectName)
    {
        var props = objectType.GetType().GetProperties();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\ObjectPropertiesOutput.txt", true))
        {
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = null", objectName, p.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose I shall write a little lightweight GUI to do this for me as I continue to explore these APIs.

Comment: Now all you need to do is wrap this into a Roslyn based addin and it'll be integrated into the IDE.

Comment: It's a shame this answer was posted and accepted instead of giving that credit to [the answer on which it is based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637265/150605) that introduced the core concept.  Wrapping the code in a `ObjectGenerateNullValues()` method is a superficial change.  The only other difference is the use of a `StreamWriter`, which actually makes this code _less_ flexible than `Console.WriteLine()`; that would allow you to copy directly from the console window, or use redirection (`>`) to instead write to a file (_any_ file).  -1 because neither change warrants a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contact obj = new Contact();
        var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in props)
            Console.WriteLine("contact.{0}= null;", p.Name);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Then copy paste the console screen or write it to a file instead.

Comment: Good advice, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  This would require me to type out all the properties manually in that Contact class.

Comment: No, you don't need to rewrite the Contact class. This is only useful in that example. You have the class already in some API, the obj.GetType().GetProperties() call will give you all the properties.

Comment: I have no issue getting the properties, as Intellisense makes that a breeze.  This issue is getting these properties and generating assignment code for each one, so I can begin to assign them to various variables and values contained in my preexisting code.

Comment: obj.GetType().GetProperties() gets you the list of properties at runtime, p.SetValue(obj, initializer) does the assignment. You can also filter by property name if you have special cases or by types etc...

Comment: Jonathan, you're on the right track here.  I've created something extending what you've written, I'll post it momentarily.

Answer (score 3):

It's been years old but I am posting this since I stumbled upon it and currently there's  a solution.
If you are using ReSharper, you can use the object's initializer.

```
var contact = new Contact()
{

};
```

While inside the brackets of the initializer, you'll get the Resharper's "light bulb". Clicking on it, you are offered the option to "Initialize members". You'll get all properties initialized to their type's default value and you can go on from there, changing those you want.
You can even select all of them and extract them into simple assignment statements if the initializer doen't fit your needs

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Visual Studio Snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) with [replacements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165396(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                 <ID>AddressId</ID>
                 <ToolTip>Enter Address</ToolTip>
                 <Default>Address</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                 <ID>Anniversary</ID>
                 <ToolTip>Enter Anniversary</ToolTip>
                 <Default>Anniversary</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[contact.AddressId = $AddressId$;
             contact.Anniversary = $Anniversary$;]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Comment: I suppose this helps, but doesn't really solve my problem of having to do this with multiple classes coming from the API.  I'm trying to avoid typing out each of the 40 properties that define these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not what you actually want but instead of repeating `contact.Property1, contact.Property2` you can use object initializer:

```
var contact = new Contact
{
    AddressId = foo1,
    Anniversary = foo2,
    AssistantId = foo3,
    BirthDay = foo4,
    Children = foo5,
    CompanyAddressInfo = foo6,

    // ... others fields
}
```

Comment: Right, I'm looking for a way to auto-generate this code right here with null values or whatever for placeholders.

Comment: if you intentionally omit some property, it will be initialized by default value. In particular `null` for reference types.